# Using egrep to check the length of a string

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

Hi so I'm new to using egrep and I'm having a bit of trouble trying to get this to work

So I have a textfile with one word in it and I need to check the length of the word

I'm testing if the word is between 6 to 32 characters long and here's the command that I'm using

```
egrep '.{6,32}' file.txt
```

It does detect that the word is less than 6 characters but it doesn't work for words longer than 32 characters long

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just put the word in a variable, and use `${#variable}` to get its length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `^` (matches at the beginning of the string) and `$` (matches at end of the string) to match the whole word:

```
egrep '^.{6,32}$' file.txt
```